# Find multiple file with name (shell unix)

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I want to delete all files with names like: `*~ or #*#`.
I have tried:

```
find "dir" -name '#*#' -or -name '*~' -delete
```

but it only deletes files with ~ at the end and not files with # at the beginning and the end

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to delete `#foo#`?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to specify a pattern with the `-name` primary; `##` would match a file named exactly `##`, while `*##` would match any file that ends with `##`. Second, you need to group the two uses of `name` so that either one matching will count as a match to be deleted.

```
find dir \( -name '*##' -or -name '*~' \) -delete
```

Comment: I try this and it doesn't works copy exactly what you write and I have an error : find: ): no beginning '('

Answer (score 0):

How about find with `-regex` switch:

```
find -E . -regex "^./(~|##)$" -exec rm '{}' \;
```

`-E` is being used to support extended (modern) regular expression feature.

Comment: If my directory is for example /home/test what am i supposed to write exactly ? (I don't understand where to put the path)

Comment: Just use this command: `find -E /home/test -regex "^./(~|##)$" -exec rm '{}' \;`

Comment: I write : find -E /home/tesrt -name "^./(*~|#*#)$" -print and it find nothing (I have some files with *~ or #*#)

Comment: Ok this this one: `find -E /home/test -regex "^./\*?(~|#\*?#)$" -exec rm '{}' \;`

Answer (score 0):

I find my solutiom : find dir -name "*~" -delete -or -name "#*#" -delete
Thanks everyone